# Como instalar uma versão anterior no Angular

Tags: angular

Boa noite, minha pergunta é bem simples, porém não achei a resposta, como eu instalo uma versão 4 do Angular, se a atual está na 6?

Tentei `npm install -g @angular/cli@4` ou `npm install -g @angular/cli@4.1.0`

Não aceita, dá erro!

Obrigada!

Comment: Caso a solução abaixo não de certo, você poderia informar qual erro está acontecendo?
Outra coisa que você pode tentar é, vá na pasta do projeto e delete a pasta node_modules. depois execute os comandos conforme resposta abaixo.

Comment: É para criação de um novo projeto ou algum já existente?

Comment: É um projeto novo!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que basta desinstalar o Angular globalmente e instalar a versão 4.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.1
```

Comment: Tentei, essa opção, mas pelo que entendi, ela instala a versão 1 e se tento: npm install -g @angular/cli@4 não vai..

Comment: É que para usar Angular 4, você precisa do CLI 1.4. Por isso parece confuso.

Comment: Até o `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0` deve rodar com Angular 4.

Comment: Encontrei algumas informações que pode ajudar você a compreender melhor esses setups `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230917/how-to-install-angular-cli-with-angular-v4-x`.

Comment: Ahh, perfeito, entendi! Muito obrigada pela ajuda!